# Hadoop and Cassandra - InvalidRequestException(why:Column timestamp required)

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I have a simple mapred job running on my Cassandra cluster, but when it tries to save the output to a table I get InvalidRequestException(why:Column timestamp required).

I've tried manually adding a 'timestamp' column to the CF but it doesnt make any difference.

Here's the description of my CF (as interpreted by cqlsh):

```
CREATE TABLE output_words (
  key text PRIMARY KEY,
  "count" int,
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_On_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

I'm using POM with hadoop-core v1.1.2 and cassandra-thrift v1.2.4 on top of Cassandra v1.2.4

Can anyone suggest how to get around this?

**Additional info**

Im configuring my job as follows (only showing config relevant to the output):

```
Job job = new Job(getConf(), "wordcount");

job.setJarByClass(TestJob.class);
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(ReducerToCassandra.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(ByteBuffer.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(List.class);

job.setOutputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.class);

ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), _keyspace, OUTPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY);

ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), _port);
ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), _host);
ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner");
```

And my reducer class:

```
public static class ReducerToCassandra extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, ByteBuffer, List<Mutation>>
{
    public void reduce(Text word, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(StringSerializer.get().toByteBuffer(word.toString()), Collections.singletonList(getMutation(word, sum)));
    }

    private static Mutation getMutation(Text word, int sum) {
        Column c = new Column();
        c.name = StringSerializer.get().toByteBuffer("count");
        c.value = IntegerSerializer.get().toByteBuffer(sum);
        c.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;

        Mutation m = new Mutation();
        m.column_or_supercolumn = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
        m.column_or_supercolumn.column = c;
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: which API are you using for storing the MR job result in cassandra?

Comment: Im just using hadoop (I think). Ive added code snippets showing how Im configuring the job, and the reducer class. Does it look sound to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

`c.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;`

Can you try this

```
c.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000)
```

Comment: Actually this is a thrift way of implementing timestamp upgraded since 0.7 version. cheers